# Wordpress rest API returning 404?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, wordpress-rest-api

I have a WP installation in my server that uses WP as an API. I use a few plugins to get my data:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-frontpage/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-api-menus/

My theme is a react app that uses the WP rest API to get info.

This was working fine. I installed WP, the plugins and things went smoothly.

I was doing a few things through FTP on friday and accidentally deleted the .htaccess file's contents (not the file itself). While this file was empty, I updated the permalink's structure. I noticed I broke the blog's frontpage (admin works fine) and restored the htaccess and enabled the permalink setting that I thought was enabled before (fresh install, I think it was the "Month and name" setting that was enabled by default).

For some reason, the API urls now return 404 when permalinks are enabled.

If I use the "Plain" setting on permalinks, things almost work (the frontpage plugin is broken, but that's another story I think).

Anyone has an idea of what might've gone wrong or how I fix it? Here's a link to the live site: http://enrique-ramirez.com/dk/ it'll probably have the Plain setting enabled, though.

This is my current `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**UPDATE** So if I try to GET this link: `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` it will fail, but if I append `index.php` it works (so `/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`. Notice that I'm not using URL params). [I read somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34743649/1202841) that I might need to enable mod_rewrite in my apache? But this was working before... so I'm now even more confused.

Comment: Your .htaccess file looks good, and should work without index.php appended to the API-path. If you save a page on the server with <? phpinfo(); ?> and visit it in the browser, and then search for mod_rewrite, does it appear as active? Is it hosted on a native Apache? Or emulated? Path to .htaccess might differ depending on this.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I've created a test.php file with phpinfo(); in it, I cannot find mod_rewrite in the file. Maybe something is amiss with my server rather than my WP installation. You can check the file here: http://enrique-ramirez.com/dk/test.php

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670533/wordpress-rest-api-wp-api-404-error

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same issue which points to rewrites not being enabled. However, my server had the rewrite module enabled and the same `.htaccess` file as above.

The problem was that the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` wasn't allowing .htaccess override files:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Changing `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` resolved the issue. Make sure you are targeting the right `Directory` where your WP site lives!

Then restart your apache process:

```sh
sudo service apache2 restart
```

*Note: If you have configured your rest API endpoint to be something other than the default `wp-json` you might need to go to Dashboard -> Settings and change your permalink settings, then revert it back to what it was. This will rebuild the rewrite cache.*

Answer (score 2):

For Nginx server,
open /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com

Change "location /" part to

```
location / {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

Then restart your Nginx server:

```
service nginx restart
```

Comment: This worked for me.