# Is any simple rest api simple endpoint for posts in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am working with wordpress 4.9. I am trying to use new rest api. Is some api enpoints imlpemented by default? There is no `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` nor `/wp-json/wp/` nor `/wp-json/` is accessible. The `404` is answer. What I need to check or enable? Is any ready stub snippet to make posts rest api endpoint?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670533/wordpress-rest-api-wp-api-404-error

Answer (score 1):

Change the permalink setting. Maybe you can set permalink by post name.

```
Dashbord->Settings->Permalink
```

After saving changes `https://****.**/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/` should work.

if it not works, maybe you need to enable `mod_rewrite`, on ubuntu:

```
a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thank you. It is useful, upvoted. Actually the problem in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually rest url is differ or was recunfigured in wordpress I am working with.

The url in my case is `https://{site}/rest_api/wp/v2`

The actual `url` of the rest is possible to figure out by the next code:

```php
echo get_rest_url();
```