# Why using Gatsby Wordpress plugin throws 404 error?

Tags: php, wordpress, gatsby

I'm setting up a Gatsby site that pulls data from an existing wordpress site that I host on my own server [Dreamhost].

After I set up the plugin according to the docs and when I run 'gatsby develop', this happens. No data object is returned.. the plugin I installed on the wordpress site seems to do nothng.

> =START PLUGIN=====================================
>
> Site URL: https://example.com
>
> Site hosted on Wordpress.com: false
>
> Using ACF: false
>
> Auth: false
>
> Verbose output: true
>
> Mama Route URL: https://example.com/wp-json
>
> ⡀ source and transform nodes
>
> Path: /wp-json
>
> The server response was "404 Not Found"
>
> error Plugin gatsby-source-wordpress returned an error
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
>
> ====================================================

I have the https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth installed and activated.. and indeed, no /wp-json.

What am I missing?

I feel like the issue is with my WP-API plugin or Wordpress settings.

*the example.com is used for privacy sake in the above

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Comment: Is `baseUrl` inside the `gatsby-source-wordpress` config options set to your WordPress URL or to `example.com`? Can you access https://example.com/wp-json (replace with your WP site's URL) in your browser? You shouldn't need any authentication set up to access `/wp-json`

Comment: Yep, my baseUrl is set to my Wordpress URL. mysite.com/wp-json gives me 404. The Wordpress site is installed at /dev on the server. I've tried mysite.com/dev/wp-json with no luck, also dev.mysite.com/wp-json just for the heck of it and got 404.

Comment: @honeymkr have you found a solution for this problem ? I'm running the same one.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670533/wordpress-rest-api-wp-api-404-error).

> I also faced similar problem in a local project. I used index.php after my project url and it worked.
>   `http://localhost/myproject/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

Try to access `[yourwordpresssite.com]/index.php/wp-json/` and see if it works.

If yes then go to gatsby-config.js and ammend `restApiRoutePrefix:"index.php/wp-json"`

Comment: This worked for me, but I'm wondering if a better fix is to reorganize the file structure?

Answer (score 0):

I talk about using `gatsby-source-wordpress` in a series at https://www.iamtimsmith.com/blog/how-to-build-a-blog-with-wordpress-and-gatsby-part-1/.

If you can see some json at `mysite.com/dev/wp-json/wp/v2/pages` then the problem lies within a query in the Gatsby project. If you can't get to a json object at `mysite.com/dev/wp-json/wp/v2/pages` then the problem lies within the WordPress installment and Gatsby can't find the rest api.