# Permalinks ERROR 404 when I change it in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When I change my permalinks from Plain to other option and I go to edit/update some page I reveive the following error in the Chrome console

> wp-json/wp/v2/pages/201?_locale=user 404 (Not Found)

And if I try to see the preview I receive 404

**EDIT**:

This is my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /html/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /html/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: what is in your .htaccess file?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: Are you using the Wordpress REST API?

Comment: No, the only plugin that I am using is Yoast

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34743649/7077417