# Woocommerce REST API - Nginx - Error 404 Not Found

Tags: rest, nginx, woocommerce, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to use the **Woocommerce** (v 3.5.4) **Rest Api** on my VPS (**debian 9, Nginx**).

Everything works well in my local machine (**windows 10, XAMPP**).

**wpbop/** is the folder (var/www/wpbop/) where the wordpress files are stored.

The next basic URL in a browser should send the endpoints of the API (no need of athentication for this first step) :
**http://*my-public-ip*/wpbop/wp-json/wc/v3**

Or a curl in command line

**curl http://127.0.0.1/wpbop/wp-json/wc/v3**

in both cases, i get error 404 Not Found.

I can acces to the blog / admin blog without any problems ( **http://*my-public-ip*/wpbop** )

My permalinks are set on "Postname" in wordpress admin panel, this is recommanded by many people in same case.

---

## **EDIT - SOLUTION :**

Since my Wordpress installation is in a sub-domain,

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

**can't find index.php. Just change this line by :**

try_files $uri $uri/ /wpbop/index.php$is_args$args;

### and it works !

---

Perhaps problem is coming from my Nginx conf file ?

```
server {
  server_name localhost;
  listen 80;
  root /var/www;

    location /wpbop {

        index index.php;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/blog.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/blog.error.log;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried many things without any results, and I'm stuck for several days. Can someone help me ?
Thanks for reading me.

Comment: It looks like you found a solution. The best thing to do is not to add the solution to your question, but to post a new answer to your own question and then accept your own answer

Comment: Allowing * origins is a security issue.

Answer (score 3):

This case need a simple fix in the NGINX configuration file. This is related to the path of my wordpress installation.

Since my Wordpress installation is in a sub-domain,

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

--> can't find index.php. Just change this line by :

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /wpbop/index.php$is_args$args;
```

Answer (score 2):

when you get 404 code. try to access `http://yoursite/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts`

Official documents https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/key-concepts

Answer (score 0):

Move `root /var/www/;` by one level up (to `server` context). It is not being inherited.

Comment: Ok I tried this. Unfortunatly I get same behavior, still 404 not found with my API calls : (