# Wordpress Contact Form 7 does not work due to URL structure

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

On example.org/contact everthing works fine.
When i swtich language (Weglot) to example.org/de/contact - nothing happens when I submit the form, only infinite spinning.

In console i get:

```
"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" 
/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/4833/feedback
```

As a result of wp-json, I get this response:

```
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}
```

Error log on server:

```
"POST /wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/4833/feedback HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "https://example.org/de/contact" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36" 0.066 "runtime: proxy" "server: example.com"
"GET /wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/4833/feedback HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "https://example.org/de/contact" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36" 0.068 "runtime: proxy" "server: example.com"
```

When I add to my theme:
`add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_js', '__return_false' );` It works on translated pages, but i want ajax sbumit.

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Anyone has ideas? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: check your server settings/htaccess to make sure `/wp-json/` is  accessible.

Comment: @Aurovrata my htaccess is default wordpress hta. When i open
/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/4833/feedback i get multiple redirections like this https://imgur.com/a/g1OxI6L and then  https://imgur.com/a/yAqsDF6 404:

Comment: when accessing `/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/4833/feedback` from your browser you should get a JSON response and not a 404.  This is an indication that your server is redirecting or blocking the page, see some of the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670533/wordpress-rest-api-wp-api-404-error-cannot-access-the-wordpress-rest-api).