# rename name in contact from 7 before submit

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

Im trying to rename name of input in contact from 7. There is integration with google sheets, and name of input must be same as is named a column in the sheet. Issue is when you need two words name, its not supported.

Here is code what should rename input:

```
function custom_rename_form_field($contact_form) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ($submission) {
        $data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        
        if (isset($data['jaky-obchod'])) {
            $jakyObchodValue = $data['jaky-obchod'];
            
            unset($data['jaky-obchod']);
            
            $data['Jaký obchod'] = $jakyObchodValue;
            
            $submission->set_posted_data($data);
        }
    }
}
```

But im getting error 500.

name "jaky-obchod" should be renamed to "Jaký obchod" before contact from 7 send data

Comment: http 500 is server related not code related.

Comment: Check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670533/wordpress-rest-api-wp-api-404-error-cannot-access-the-wordpress-rest-api -  Also your code can be simplified, since the third param of `brefore_send_mail` is `$submission`

Answer (score 0):

What about this ? Try wpcf7_before_send_mail hook instead of wpcf7_submit...

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'custom_rename_form_field');

function custom_rename_form_field($contact_form) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ($submission) {
        $data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        
        if (isset($data['jaky-obchod'])) {
            $jakyObchodValue = $data['jaky-obchod'];
            
            unset($data['jaky-obchod']);
            
            $data['Jaký_obchod'] = $jakyObchodValue;
            
            $submission->set_posted_data($data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Same error as wpcf7_submit: "code":"rest_no_route" in /wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/299/feedback